# rsync script to nightly backup var

Tags: linux, backup, ubuntu

Having trouble with making a backup script for automatically updating the var folder to another server nightly

```
BDATE=`date +%F`
 rsync --exclude=foldera/folderb -bavz --backup-dir=backup-$(BDATE) root@someserver.com:/path/to/var
```

This doesn't seem to be working when I run it, have I done something wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a first glance, your problem seems to be the --backup-dir flag. The $(BDATE) won't expand to the date. Just try this from a terminal:

BDATE="14-06-2011"

echo $BDATE  --> 14-06-2011

echo foo-$(BDATE) --> DATE: command not found  foo-

if you use this foo-$BDATE it will work:
echo foo-$BDATE --> foo-14-06-2011

Also, can you please post the output if it still doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

`$( )` is command substitution, like the backticks:  ``` `` ``` If you are trying isolate a variable you use curly braces, e.g., `${foo}_bar` will reference the var `foo`. In this case, `$BDATE` doesn't need any such isolation. FYI `$(( ))` is arithmetic evaluation.